# Is there a way to play audio without calling the connect command? (pycord)

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, pycord

In my implementation whenever I call the play method while the bot is connected to the voice channel, it will throw an error. However, the official documentation, including other videos on the matter, use the same method. The main reason I found is that the call for the [connect method](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) is necessary, as it values 'voice' as a [VoiceProtocol](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/voice.html#discord.VoiceProtocol), which is further necessary to use the [play method](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/voice.html#discord.VoiceClient.play) for playing audio.

```
@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=\[\])
async def play(ctx, audio):
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
voice = await channel.connect()
audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=f'audio/{audio}.mp3', executable='C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe')
voice.play(audio_source)
await ctx.respond(f'Now playing `{audio}`')
```

If the bot is already in the voice channel when I call

```
voice = await channel.connect()
```

then it will throw the error

> discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.

This is the exact method the official documentation of pycord uses to play audio [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/migrating_to_v1.html#voice-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the voice client from [`guild.voice_client`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.voice_client). Check that before connecting

```py
if ctx.guild.voice_client:
    voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
else:
    voice = await channel.connect()
```